# Installing TortoiseHG on Gnome in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, mercurial, gnome, tortoisehg

I followed the following steps to install TortoiseHG on Ubuntu 9.10 using the following document:

http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/nautilus

I get the following error in my ~/.xsession-errors

```
evolution-alarm-notify-Message:  Tue Dec  1 23:28:26 2009

sys:1: GtkWarning: Refusing to add non-unique action 'HgNautilus::00None' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
sys:1: GtkWarning: gtk_action_get_name: assertion `GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed
sys:1: GtkWarning: gtk_ui_manager_add_ui: assertion `name != NULL || type == GTK_UI_MANAGER_SEPARATOR' failed
sys:1: GtkWarning: Refusing to add non-unique action 'HgNautilus::01clone' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
sys:1: GtkWarning: Refusing to add non-unique action 'HgNautilus::02init' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
sys:1: GtkWarning: Refusing to add non-unique action 'HgNautilus::03userconfig' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
sys:1: GtkWarning: Refusing to add non-unique action 'HgNautilus::05about' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hgtk", line 44, in <module>
    sys.exit(hggtk.hgtk.dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/hggtk/hgtk.py", line 29, in dispatch
    u = _ui.ui(traceback='--traceback' in args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'traceback'
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?  Meanwhile I'll be using the command line.  Thanks.

Comment: what's your hg version? Usually thg wants a bleeding edge hg (eg 1.4 or 1.4.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using Mercurial 1.2.1, which does not have the refactoring done in [revision 6b5522cb2ad2](http://www.selenic.com/hg/rev/6b5522cb2ad2). That means that you cannot use the latest version of TortoiseHg with such an old version of Mercurial.

I suggest updating Mercurial to a newer version or use an older version of TortoiseHg.

Comment: That's funny, when I run "hg version" it tells me that I'm running version 1.3.1...could it be something else?

Comment: I would still suggest that you try matching versions of Mercurial and TortoiseHg.